# How to implement character restriction using regex in java?

Tags: javascript, java

Basically i have `String restrict = "Hello+Hi";` which i want to restrict all characters other than `(/^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#\(\.)]$/)` using regex.

in javascript this is how it's being done 
`field.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$%&^*()-_=.<>?)\(\)]+$/)`
which will restrict all the characters between parenthesis.

i want my string to only contain `(/^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#\(\.)]$/)`

i really appreciate if somebody tell me how to do this in java.

Comment: Personally, I don't think you are making much sense. Your supposed requirements don't seem to match what your example javascript appears to do...

Comment: i updated my question please read the new line.

Comment: If you want to have more possibilities you can use java.util.Regex. More you can find there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.matches`, which will match the whole `String` with a pattern.

In this case: `"Hello+Hi".matches("\\p{Alpha}+")` will return `false` because `+` is not a word character.

To avoid confusion: the `+` in the pattern is a greedy quantifier for 1+ character repeats.

The `p{Alpha}` represents alphabetic characters, and requires double-escaping.

See docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Edit**

Since you edited your requirement, just use the custom class as follows, plus the quantifier:

```
"Hello+World".matches("[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#\\().]+") // returns false because of the +
```

Comment: Nit: `\w` also includes `_` and `0-9`, so it isn't quite the same as OP's restriction.

Comment: hey can you read my question again i added a new line for what exactly i want?